# Change the default moving distance

Tags: transforms, customization

In Blender, I can move the model in default distance by holding the control. However, can I change the default moving setting by myself?

Comment: what kind of default moving setting would you like?

Comment: @moonboots like moving the distance in 10 centimeters by holding control

Comment: you mean like a kind of custom increment snap? You could temporarly change the grid units in the Scene panel > Units > Unit System